# DevExpress RowUpdating old values returning text value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I have a DevExpress ASPXGridView which has been bound with a dataset.

I'm using the edit row command to edit the data in the row and return it to the database.

When the edit button is clicked, the row opens up and there is an ASPXComboBox that is bound to another dataset. The TextField and the ValueField have both been properly set in the ASPXComboBox and are displaying data correctly. The data is as shown

1. List item
2. List item

When e.NewValues("") is called the integer value field i.e 1 is returned. However, when e.OldValues("") the TextField is returned i.e. "List Item"

Is there a way of returning the the integer value when calling e.Oldvalues without having to make another call to the database?

Thanks